# Python: Access the next element in XML using ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

My `XML` file has no tags, which makes parsing not so friendly. I'm trying to find an element and change it:

```
...        
    <dict>
        <key>Arguments</key>
            <dict>
                <key>TestArchive</key
                <string>testArchive.tar</string>
            </dict>
            ....
    </dict>
...
```

What I'm trying to do is to get and change "testArchive.tar" string, because this string may change every time, I use TestArchive as an anchor

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
with open ('file.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for item in tree.iter():
    if item.text == "TestArchive":
         ....
```

How can I get the next element? Which in my case supposed to be the item I'm looking for?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I could find is to use `enumerate()` and index the parent as a list. In your case:

```py
items = list(tree.iter())
for i, item in enumerate(items):
    if item.text == "TestArchive":
         next_item = items[i + 1]
```

Answer (score -3):

You need to use `getnext()` on your key element. This will get the next sibling.

```
if item.text == "TestArchive":
    name = item.getnext()
    print name.text
```

Comment: when I do  `if item.text == "TestArchive: item.getnext()`   - Element has no attribute "getnext"

Comment: Why are you comparing the text? You have the `item`, go `item.getnext()` if the condition is true.

Comment: `getnext()` returns the next following sibling of an element. This method is available in [lxml](http://lxml.de), but not in the ElementTree standard module (which is what the OP uses).

Comment: Does anyone have a solution that uses elementtree? Getnext() is exactly what I need. But I'm also using elementtree.